# Difficulty with Nested IF in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

So, what I want this formula to do is look at cells I3, K3 and M3 and to place results in R1. If cells K3 and M3 are at 0, then I want 50% of I3 to be placed in R1. If K3 has any value above 0, and M3 is at 0, I want 75% of I3 in R1. If both K3 and M3 have a value above 0, I want either 75% of I3 OR M3+K3 in cell R1, whichever is higher.

I put together a formula that I thought would accomplish this, and it works up until the last either or part, and always gives me 75% even if m3+k3 is higher. I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong, and thought maybe it would be obvious to someone else. Any help would be appreciated.

My formula:
=IF(K3+M3=0,I3*0.5,IF(K3>0,I3*0.75,IF(AND(M3>0, (K3+M3>I3*0.75)),K3+M3,I3*0.75)))

Answer (score 1):

It is often helpful to write these things out in an indented fashion:

```
=IF(K3+M3=0,                                -if they both are 0
    I3*0.5,                                     -then half of I3
    IF(K3>0,                                    -else if k3 is > 0
        I3*0.75,                                    -then I3*.75  *****
        IF(AND(M3>0, (K3+M3>I3*0.75))               -else if M3 > 0 and K+M > I3*.75
            ,K3+M3,                                    -then K3+M3
            I3*0.75)))                                 -else i3 * .75
```

***** = This line will always be evaluated if K3 > 0 and stop processing the rest of the formula.

To get the result you need to change that line to:

```
MAX((I3*0.75),(K3+M3))
```

Making the full formula:

```
=IF(K3+M3=0,I3*0.5,IF(K3>0, MAX((I3*0.75),(K3+M3)),IF(AND(M3>0, (K3+M3>I3*0.75)),K3+M3,I3*0.75)))
```

So basically if K3 > 0, take the max of I3*.75 or K3+M3

Answer (score 0):

Try this out

=IF(K3+M3=0,I3*0.5,IF(AND(K3>0,M3<=0),I3*0.75,IF(AND(M3>0,K3>0),IF(M3+K3>I3*0.75,M3+K3,I3*0.75))))